# How can I add / remove classes to an element via AngularJS that's out of $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a DOM element called `.nav-bar`. I want to add a class to it from another Angular controller that has it's own `$scope`. Is such a thing possible?

I have a navigation bar that needs to be loaded one of several controllers. Depending on which controller / view loads it, it has to have a class conditionally applied.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what (and why) you're trying to do. The solution in angular rarely involves adding a class from a controller.

Comment: you can do it with jQuery/jqLite via directive

Comment: @MikeRobinson, clarified in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your navigation bar should be its own directive and live outside the scope of those controllers. I have solved a similar problem by letting my main module own that directive and spin it up and having my controllers live in separate modules that are injected into the parent app.

The best solution for conditionally classing it is to look at the route params or the location in the directive link or controller and figure out which controller they are on and set a scope variable that reflects it. Then, in the view, use ng-class to set the proper class depending on the variable's value.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to give you some more direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could change a class on the body element from anywhere.  Create a top level `AppCtrl` and put it on the html element like this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as appCtrl">
    <body class="{{ appCtrl.appService.cssClass }}"></body>
</html>

myModule.controller('AppCtrl', ['appService', function(appService) {
    this.appService = appService;
}]);
```

Then have an of `AppService` which is injected into the `AppCtrl` and the service is assigned `this.appService` in the controller.  The service can contain a property to contain the class you want to assign.  Now you can assign the class from anywhere by injecting appService.  You could do something similar on any element, it doesn't have to be on the html/body elements.

I think the "Ctrl as ctrl" syntax requires at least Angular 1.1.5.